# Three.js: Convert 6 Cube Image into 6 Textures

Tags: javascript, three.js

For my `three.js` project I am using this method to load 6 images for panoramic texture cube:

```
function getTextureCube(){
  var urls = ["1.png","2.png","3.png","4.png","5.png","6.png"];
  var loader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
  var textureCube = loader.load(urls);
  return textureCube;
}
```

and then set into uniforms like this:

```
uniforms[ "tCube" ].value = getTextureCube();
```

However, I prefer to load one panoramic cube image similar to this:
[image: similar to this]
 and convert into 6 textures on the fly with JavaScript, instead of loading 6 separate images. How can I do this?

[This example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_panorama_cube.html) seems to do image conversion into 6 textures (see `getTexturesFromAtlasFile` method) but it works for simple `MeshBasicMaterial` and not custom one like `ShaderMaterial` which I have.

I thought about converting 6 piece cube image into 6 data64 sets, but with large resolution cube image data64 strings will be extremely huge.

How do I convert single 6 piece image into 6 textures for custom `ShaderMaterial`?

Comment: if the texture is in the format you have in the example then in your fragment shader you just need to compute a texel x-offset. Dividing the x-coord by 6 and adding `1/6 * texture_num_you_want_to_access` should work. `texture_num_you_want_to_access` should be a number from 0 to 5.

Comment: In pure WebGL You can load whole image data, then divid it into several buffers, and finally use each buffer to recompose each cube texture faces. But the problem here is that you have Three.js as intermediate between you and WebGL and i have no clue about how Three.js allows to customize such process.